# How to resize a Gif without losing quality in c#

Tags: c#, .net

i use this:

```
    using (var image = Image.FromFile(txtSource.Text))
    using (var newImage = 
                resize_percentage(image,Convert.ToInt32(percentageValue.Text)))
    {newImage.Save(txtPathDirectory.Text + "\\" + fileName, ImageFormat.Gif);}
```

its correct but when i use it i lose the quality.

Comment: Are you making it _bigger_ or _smaller_?  If you make it smaller you're going to lose resolution - period.  If you're making it bigger you'll need to use some sort of interpolation to fill in the gaps.

Comment: Any manipulation will cause you to loose quality.  There are different resizing algorithms, and which one to use really depends on the content.  However, you will _always_ loose quality if you change the size of the image.

Comment: Especially on a primitive file format like Gif, 256 colors is not nearly enough to smoothen-out the interpolation artifacts.  High time to retire it, use Png instead.

Comment: You failed to post the most important part. If you want us to tell you whether you're getting the best possible resizing, you have to show us the `resize_percentage` method.

Comment: You can't gain quality from nothing. The new pixels will need to be interpolated/blended/scaled from surrounding pixels. The "perfect lossless scaling algorithm" is an impossibility. Period.

Answer (score 1):

Install **Magick.NET** via NuGet, license can be found here:
https://magick.codeplex.com/license

Example code:

```
var newWidth = 100;
using (var collection = new MagickImageCollection(new FileInfo(@"C:\test.gif")))
{
    collection.Coalesce();
    foreach (var image in collection)
    {
        image.Resize(newWidth, 0);
    }
    collection.Write(@"c:\resized.gif");
}
```

From my tests, this works with alpha channels and varying frame rates.  RE quality, comments give good answers.

Comment: I believe you should have addressed the nature of inherent quality loss while scaling/interpolation/... There is no true "lossless scaling" ...